# Pikachoose thumbnail carousel not working

Tags: thumbnails, carousel, pikachoose

I am using the Pikachoose plugin for the image galleries on my website (http://www.clare-eileen-callahan.com/inthehangar/). Everything seems to be working except for the thumbnail carousel. They just pile up on the bottom of the page, where I want the carousel to be horizontally scrollable, so that only x amount of thumbnails are visible. I can't figure out what is going on with the CSS and Javascript that is preventing it from displaying as it should.

Here is the code I'm using: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybExq

Sorry there is a lot of it for the plug in!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, there was an unexpected element in the original jquery carousel script. I was able to find it by breaking apart the script into short lines and referring back to the console.